# convert second into hours and minutes using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

how to convert `seconds` into `hours` and `minutes` using `moment.js`?
for example: convert `02:40` into `2 hours 40 minutes`.Any help will be appreciated.please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You really dont need moment for this. Just use split on this and concatenate `hours` and `minutes`.

```js
function formateTime(time){
  const s = time.split(":");
  return +s[0]+" hours "+(+s[1])+" minutes";
}

console.log(formateTime("02:40"))
```

Comment: I have DataTable and within that I want to format data like this :                        
  {data: 'time', name: 'time',
   render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        return (new Date(data * 1000)).toUTCString().match(/(\d\d:\d\d)/)[0];
                       }

Comment: Yea so you can use this function.

Comment: how to use this function with data-table?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
moment().format('hh [hours] mm [minutes]');
```

Provide more information, if it doesn't works.

Comment: Write the object that you are trying to convert.

Comment: {data: 'time', name: 'time',
                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                       return fromatted_time;
                    }.this is data-table renderer and I want it returns 2 hours 3 min.  data is recently like 203.54